# UTF characters in listings

Tags: listings, unicode, input-encodings

I use `lstlistings` for code and a lot of special characters can be displayed with `literate`. See my MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings,textcomp,eurosym}
\begin{document}
\lstset{extendedchars=true,language=java,basicstyle=\ttfamily,showspaces=false,showstringspaces=false,literate=%
{€}{\euro}1%
{§}{\S}1%
{°}{\textdegree{}}1%
{ä}{{\"a}}1%
{ö}{{\"o}}1%
{ü}{{\"u}}1%
{ß}{{\ss}}1%
{Ä}{{\"A}}1%
{Ö}{{\"O}}1%
{Ü}{{\"U}}1%
{µ}{\textmu}1%
} 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
// only for demonstration purposes
  public class keystrokes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("keystrokes on a German keyboard: €§°äöüßÄÖÜµ");
    }
  }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know, how I can literate the following characters: ¹²³¼½¢

Comment: I am not sure, but i think there mitght be a glyph available through package `textcomp` (try `\textonehalf`). But LuaLaTeX quite possibly will do the job good.

Comment: If your listings contain Unicode, you would be better off using `minted` or `pythontex` than using `listings`.

Comment: now I found a solution `{½}{{\sfrac{1}{2}}}1{¼}{{\sfrac{1}{4}}}1{¢}{\textcent}1{¹}{{\textsuperscript{1}}}1{²}{{\textsuperscript{2}}}1{³}{{\textsuperscript{3}}}1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see nothing strange with

```
\lstset{
  extendedchars=true,
  language=java,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  literate=%
    {€}{\euro}1%
    {§}{\S}1%
    {°}{\textdegree{}}1%
    {ä}{{\"a}}1%
    {ö}{{\"o}}1%
    {ü}{{\"u}}1%
    {ß}{{\ss}}1%
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1%
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1%
    {µ}{\textmu}1%
    {¹}{{\textsuperscript{1}}}1%
    {²}{{\textsuperscript{2}}}1%
    {³}{{\textsuperscript{3}}}1%
    {¼}{\textonequarter}1%
    {½}{\textonehalf}1%
    {¢}{\textcent}1%
}
```

The input

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
// only for demonstration purposes
  public class keystrokes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("keystrokes on a German
        keyboard: €§°äöüßÄÖÜµ¹²³¼½¢");
    }
  }     
\end{lstlisting}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Semi off-topic (will remove this comment): why is a second pair of braces needed sometimes? E.g., `{{\"o}}`.

Comment: @Manuel Ah, knowing why would be interesting indeed!