# Listing - invalid UTF-8

Tags: listings

What is wrong with this please? The error is:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... printf "Vytvořen

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily}     
\begin{document}
\mylisting[label=file]{Vytvoření 500 souborů \texttt{korel.res} výběrem z 65 spekter s opakováním}{files.txt}
\end{document}
```

I don't have LOG file
[image]

Comment: Compiles withput errors on TeXLive 2019. Can you provide the log file as well?

Comment: I have only files that I added to my question. I used MiKTeX

Comment: You must have  a log-file. Check the real extentions of every file in the folder (or configure windows so that it shows the endings).

Comment: Possibly related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214828/utf-characters-in-listings

Comment: Be aware that copy& paste can change code, so it is quite possible that your tex file is actually 8bit encoded and we see utf8. Try if it compiles if you add \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}.

Comment: it doesn't help. I copy the head from file that works well

Comment: The example compiles fine for me, but I'm almost 100% certain that the `file.txt` my system uses (`tex/latex/ha-prosper/Styles/Aggie\files.txt`) is not the one you have in mind. The fact that the error message you quote says `printf "Vytvořen`, which is not contained anywhere in the document makes me suspect that the issue might be with your `file.txt`. Can you check that? Can you check that your `file.txt` is encoded in UTF-8 like you expect or is it maybe in a different encoding?

Comment: `"Vytvořen` is a caption of listings. When I delete `\mylisting...` and write text instead of it, it works. How should I check encoding please?

Answer (score 1):

Run the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

[image]

Comment: It gives an error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin` in case of lualatex and when I use xelatex there is much more errors

Comment: The document as posted even compiles fine with pdfLaTeX. Indeed the error message mentioning `printf "Vytvořen`, which is nowhere to be found in the shown `.tex` code makes me suspect the issue is hidden in `file.txt`.

Comment: you do not need package `inputenc`! `utf8` is already the default